# Dojo Select - first option getting selected by default

Tags: html-select, dijit.form, dojo

I have a select box on my form which is getting displayed using addOption. Below the code for the same

```
storeData = response.myData;
var select = dijit.byId('mySelect');
select.addOption(storeData.items);
```

HTML declaration of Select box

```
<select id="mySelect" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Select" data-dojo-attach-point="mySelect" data-dojo-props="name:'mySelect', placeHolder: 'Select a value', value:''"></select>
```

In the storeData, I am returning list of JSON objects including a blank option. (label="" and value=" ");

I want the place holder text to get displayed when no option is selected. But by default first option (i.e. blank value option) is getting selected and because of that place holder text is not getting displayed. If I remove the blank value option from list of options, then the option after that is getting selected by default.

Is there any way where I can set the selection to none. Any pointer for this issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`dijit/form/Select` acts as a normal selection box element (simply said it's an enhanced form of `<select>`). It's the default behavior of such a select box to select the first option by default.

Either way, the `dijit/form/Select` widget does not support placeholders I think, neither is it documented in the [API docs](http://dojotoolkit.org/api/?qs=1.10/dijit/form/Select).

As an alternative you could use the `dijit/form/ComboBox` or `dijit/form/FilteringSelect` widget, which both support the `placeHolder` property.

Another common practice (at least with `<select>`) is that you add a default selected and disabled item, which acts as your placeholder, for example:

```html
<select name="select1" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Select">
    <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected" value="">- Select a state -</option>
    <option value="TN">Tennessee</option>
    <option value="VA">Virginia</option>
    <option value="WA">Washington</option>
    <option value="FL">Florida</option>
    <option value="CA">California</option>
</select>
```

Demo: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zcvx6b0h/)

Comment: thanks for quick reply. I had considered these options but I want the drop down to be only selectable (filtering or keying should be disabled) so I had to opt for Select box. Can we disallow keying values in Combobox or FilteringSelect?

Comment: Hmm, I don't think that's possible. An alternative is that you can make the first option of the `dijit/form/Select` disabled.